# Two classes with main methods, which will be executed first?

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

I have two classes in an application and both have main methods ,when application is executed which class's main method will be executed first ?

Comment: Welcoem to [so]! Please read [ask] and share a [mcve]!

Comment: In fact, there is not a question about order, but which method: only one will be executed, depending on configuration (which one is said to be the entry of the program).

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you to specify which class you call as the main one.

```
java com.mypackage.MyMainClass
```

Or if you have a runnable jar, the `META-INF/manifest.mf` in the jar indicates which is the  main class, like :

```
Main-Class: com.mypackage.MyMainClass
```

Now this command will call the declared main class in the jar.

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

For more details, see : [Setting an Application's Entry Point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Neither will be called *first*, because there's no *magic* executing them. You decide which one you call.

---

That a class has a `main(String...)` method merely means it *can be used* as the application's entry point (i.e. the place where execution starts), not that by some "magic" every such method *will* be executed.

Once you have a `main` method, you can call it using:

```
java path.to.my.Class
```

Alternatively, if you package your application in a `jar` file, you may indicate in its [manifest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) which class (and thus which `main` method) shall be used as the entry point.

Therefore, either way it's up to you to indicate which `main` method to call.